# How do I keep session variables in sync between Express and Socket.io in a single page app?

Tags: node.js, session, express, authentication, socket.io

I have a pretty basic single page app. I'm using middleware to attach my express session to my socket. The problem I'm having is that the middleware is run before a user is logged in. I can't figure out the best way to update the socket with the new session information. If I refresh the site after logging in it works but that's in no way ideal. Is there a way to control when a socket actually connects? I'm kind of a noob so there could be another way to handle this I haven't thought of.

Here's my server code:

```
// socket.io middleware
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    socket.session = {};

    var req = {
        "headers": {
            "cookie": socket.request.headers.cookie
        }
    }

    cookieParser()(req, null, function(){
        if( req.cookies['connect.sid'] ){
            var ifs = req.cookies['connect.sid'].slice(2);
            var c = cookieThing.unsign(ifs, config.secret)

            db.sessions.findOne({_id:c}, function(err,res){
                if( !err && res != null ){
                    var temp = JSON.parse(res.session);
                    for( var key in temp ){
                        if( key != 'cookie'){
                            console.log( 'setting ' + key + ': ' + temp[key] );
                            socket.session[key] = temp[key];
                        }
                    }
                }
                next();
            })

        } else {
            // no cookie
        }
    });
});

// user connects to socket
io.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log( client.session );
});
```

Client:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var server = io.connect();
    // a bunch of server.on() and server.emit() statements below here
</script>
```

Comment: Why doesn't the client wait to make its socket.io connection until after authentication?

Comment: Is the user logging in via socket.io, ajax, new http post etc?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not sure how to move the "var server = io.connect()" without causing other errors elsewhere. I get a bunch of "cannot call function that does not exist" errors because "server" isn't bound to the socket code before it's all initialized.

Comment: You have to put all your client initialization code into a common function and then call that function when appropriate.  You don't disclose any of that code so not much we can do to advise more specifically than that.  No different than waiting for `$(document).ready()` before doing DOM stuff.

Comment: @jfriend00 The only issue I would have at that point is what I would do if someone logs out. Actually this might work. Right now logout hits a specific route on the backend that kills the session and then reloads the entire page (which will disconnect and start a new socket). Although, I feel like there's a better way to handle it, this should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you receive the sucessful login, you need to signal socket.io to reload it's session.

**client:**

```
socket.emit('ReloadSession');
```

**Server:**

```
var express_session = require('express-session');
var sessionMiddleware = express_session({/*session config*/});

// socket.io middleware
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    var res = {};
    socket.handshake.url = '/';
    sessionMiddleware(socket.handshake,res,function(){
        socket.session = socket.handshake.session;
        socket.session.id = socket.handshake.sessionID;
        next();
    });
});

// user connects to socket
io.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log( client.session );
    socket.on('ReloadSession',function(data){
       socket.session.reload(function(){});
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm building the socket.session object myself. It doesn't actually have a 'reload' function. That would be a nice implementation though if I could figure out how to attach it like that. I was thinking i could do something similar but re-run the entire function I'm running as middleware.

Comment: what sessionStore are you using?

Comment: I'm using connect-mongo

Comment: Okay, I have updated the server code.  Please note that I define sessionMiddleware instead of configuring it inline when passing it to the express app.  You then pass sessionMiddleware to the express app, and your middleware can use it as well.  It would be "proper" to also pass it to your middleware, but it'll work this way.

Comment: Okay I tried this. Usually your "express_session()" function is used within the express middleware as well. So... "express_app.use( express_session({ session config }) )" so it's usually attached to the 'req' object in my express routes. Since we moved it out of there it's not attached anymore which I think is what you were referring to. But I can't figure out how to pass it to both.

Comment: `express_app.use(sessionMiddleware);` instead.

Comment: Ya that was my mistake I put use( sessionMiddleware() ) instead. Everything is attaching now but it's giving me "undefined is not a function" on the socket.session.reload()

Comment: Ohh, it's probably just being picky about a callback.  Code updated! (Just added `function(){}` to the reload call.)  That's what happens when you don't test code.

Comment: :/ welp. everything is functioning now but the socket.session still isn't being updated. I'm manually doing a socket.emit('ReloadSession') after I log in. I verified that the session has the right information in the database.

Comment: I also verified the session is still being attached to the 'req' object in my express routes properly. I wish I knew more about how all of this tied together to debug myself.